# Created UDIM tiles without image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, tilesize

I created some UDIM tiles in blender and everything looked good, but then i imported it into substance painter and baked and it only baked the mesh map of what was in the UV space, which included only one tile. Figured out what I did was create UDIM tiles but without adding in the image first, which is why they wouldn't show up on the drop down menu in the UV editor.

[image]

So basically if I am understanding correctly, blender thinks that all of my tiles are separate UV grids? I'm very confused.. My UV grid:

[image]

Is there any way to add an image for each UV tile, or is it too late? I tried adding in an image but it only applied on one UV square, and i can't make multiple images in one UV space, if that makes sense.
What it looks like in substance painter:

[image]
Any ideas?